# taking tuple in function argument and generate an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i need to Create a function that takes dimensions as tuples e.g.(3, 3) and a numeric value and returns a numpy array of the given dimension filled with the given value
for this i have written this below code but instead of generating an array it is showing only one number , could you please guide me where i am wrong?

```
import numpy as np
def solve(dim_tuple,fillnumber):
    dim_tuple = ()
    return np.full((dim_tuple),fillnumber)
x= solve((3,4),5)
print(x)
```

Comment: just remove `dim_tuple = ()`

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, it was caused by a typo. This does sound like a good use of `itertools.starmap`:

```
from itertools import starmap
import numpy as np

func = lambda a, b: np.full(a, b)

list(starmap(func, [((5, 5), 3)]))
```

```
[array([[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def solve(dim_tuple,fillnumber):

    return np.full(dim_tuple,fillnumber)

x= solve((3,3),5)

print(x)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).